# if $\int_\Bbb{R}\vert v\vert<\infty \rightarrow \int_\Bbb{R}\vert uv\vert<\infty$ then $u$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

> Let $u\in\mathcal{C}^0(\Bbb{R};\Bbb{R}).$
>
> Assume that for all $v\in\mathcal{C}^0(\Bbb{R};\Bbb{R})$ such that $\int_\Bbb{R}\vert v\vert$ converges then $\int_\Bbb{R}\vert uv\vert$ converges as well.

How can I prove that $u$ is bounded ?

I tried by contradiction, if I can construct a function such that $\int_\Bbb{R}\vert uv\vert$ diverges but such that $\int_\Bbb{R}\vert v\vert$ converges.

Any idea how can I do that ?

Comment: What is ${\cal C}^0$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. The space of continuous functions

Comment: BRW. After I finally found the vertical line on my keyboard , I found that to write the absolute value of x in MathJax you don't need \vert x \vert.... Just type |x|..... For  the  "norm" of x,  type \|x\|, yielding $\|x\|$ which looks better than ||x|| which yields $||x||$.... Sometimes I hit  "edit" on a Q just to see how someone made a symbol, and then hit "cancel" to cancel the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $u$ is unbounded. Take $\{x_n:n\geq 0\}\subset \Bbb R$ where $x_0=0$ (or anything in $\Bbb R$) and  $|u(x_n)|>\max (1+|u(x_{n-1})|, 1+4^n)$ for  $n\in \Bbb N.$

For each $n\in \Bbb N$ take $r_n>0$ such that

(i). The interval $J_n=[-r_n+x_n,r_n+x_n]$ satisfies $\forall x\in J_n \;(\; |u(x)-u(x_n)|<1).$

(ii).  $\;J_m\cap J_n=\emptyset$ when $ 0<m< n.$

Condition (ii) is possible. Otherwise for some  $m\in \Bbb N$  the point $x_m$ would be a limit point of the set $\{x_{n'}:n'>n\}$ for every $n>m,$ which would make $u$ unbounded on every nbhd of $x_m,$ contradicting the continuity of $u.$

Let $S=\Bbb R\setminus \cup_{n\in \Bbb N}J_n.$ There exists a continuous $v$ with $\int_S|v|<1$ such that for $x\in J_n$  we have $$v(x)=\frac {2^{-n}\cdot sgn (u(x_n))}{2r_n}$$       (Note: $sgn(y)=y/|y|$ for $y\ne 0.$)

Then $\int_{\Bbb R}|v|<2$ and $\int_{\Bbb R}|uv|\geq \sum_{n\in \Bbb N} |J_n| \cdot |4^nv(x_n)|=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}2^n=\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The following does not actually work, because $v$ is not fixed.

Hint: Assume otherwise. Using continuity, show that given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a non-empty intevral $I$ such that $|u|>n$ on $I$. Now, choose (justify this) $v$ such that $\int_\mathbb{R}|v| = 1$ and $\int_I|v| = 1.$ Then, 
$$\infty> \int_\mathbb{R}|uv|\geq\int_I|uv|>n.$$ Since $n$ is arbitrary, this gives the desired contradiction.

Comment: You're showing that there's a sequence of v_n such that integral(u * v_n) diverges as n increases. But what needs to be shown is that there is a *fixed* v such that integral from 0 to t of (u * v) diverges as *t* increases

Comment: Since $I$ and $v$ depend on $n,$  what you have is  $\forall  n\in \Bbb N \;\exists v_n  \exists I_n\; (  \int _{I_n}|v_n|=\int_{\Bbb R}|v_n|=1 \land \int_{\Bbb R} |uv_n|>n.)$  But this does not immediately imply $\exists v \;\forall n\in\Bbb N\;( \int_{\Bbb R} |v|<\infty\land \int_{\Bbb R}|uv|>n).$

Comment: @Acccumulation ,danielwainfleet right, this does not work.

Comment: This kind of "reversed quantifiers" error has even appeared in textbooks.

Answer (score -1):

Take the contrapositive: if u is unbounded, then |uv| diverges. For simplicity, I'll take u and v to be positive.

Since u is unbounded:

for all M there exists x$_M$ such that u(x$_M$)>M.

Since u is continuous: 

for all $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta _{\epsilon}$ such that if |x-x$_M$|<$\delta _{\epsilon}$ then |u(x)-u(x$_M$)|<$\epsilon$.

So now take $\epsilon$ = M/2, and it follows that if |u(x)-u(x$_M$)|<$\epsilon$ then u(x)>M/2.

So choose x$_n$ such that u(x$_n$) > 2$^n$ and x$_{n} > x_{n-1}+10$

Note that the existence of x$_{n}$ such that  x$_{n} > x_{n-1}+10$ follows from continuity (continuous functions are bounded on finite intervals, so if u is unbounded, then u must be unbounded outside of the finite interval [0,$ x_{n-1}+10$]

Choose $\delta _n$ such that

if |x$_n$-x| <  $\delta _n$ then u > (2$^n$)/2 

and

$\delta _n$ < 1

For each x$_n$, we have an interval of length 2$\delta _n$ for which u > 2$^{n-1}$.  Let v be equal to (2$^{-n}$)/$\delta _n $ on that interval. Then the integral of uv on that interval is at least 2$\delta _n $2$^{n-1}$ * 2$^{-n}$/$\delta _n $ = 1.

If we set v to be zero outside of these intervals, the total integral of uv is  the sum over all these intervals, and that sum clearly diverges. (Note that strictly speaking, this violates the continuity of v, but for each n, we can take v as going to zero in an arbitrarily small distance.)

The integral of v is its value over these intervals. For each interval, v is 2$^{-n}$ for an interval of at most 1, so the integral for each interval is at most 2$^{-n}$, which converges.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete!
Reasons:
1. Those intervals $I_n$ may overlap. Although for each $n$, $\int_{I_n} uv \geq 1$, we cannot deduce that $\int uv =\infty$.
2. The constructed $v$ is not continuous.